# Spring Redis docker compose - Not able to Access api

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, redis

I am learning docker and have a docker compose to run spring boot and redis.

DockerFile

```
FROM openjdk:12-jdk-alpine
ARG JAR_FILE=target/reactive-url-shortener-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
# cd /opt/app
WORKDIR /opt/app
# cp target/spring-boot-web.jar /opt/app/app.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
# java -jar /opt/app/app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","app.jar"]
```

docker-compose

```
version: '3'
networks:
  test:
services:
  web:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - redis
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - test
  redis:
    container_name: redis
    image: "library/redis:alpine"
    hostname: redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    networks:
      - test
```

when i tried to access my spring  api via postman or browser, i got no response

This is the error in postman `Error: socket hang up`

application properties file

```
spring.redis.host=redis
spring.redis.port=6379
```

This is the project i am trying to dockerize for my learning.

https://github.com/spring-academy/reactive-link-shortener-sample-app.

Please let me know what i am missing.

Answer (score 0):

In your Dockerfile you have to expose port 8080. In my opinion, the official Docker [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) is not entirely clear about what EXPOSE does. What we have to know is that in order to be able to connect to a port we have to expose it, and we may have to publish it if we want to connect from an outside network.

In order to expose it, you need to add the following line to the Dockerfile:

```
EXPOSE 8080
```

The Dockerfile should look something like this:

```
FROM openjdk:12-jdk-alpine
ARG JAR_FILE=target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
# cd /opt/app
WORKDIR /opt/app
# cp target/spring-boot-web.jar /opt/app/app.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
# java -jar /opt/app/app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","app.jar"]
```

Also, I've noticed that Spring will expect to connect to Redis on `localhost`. This wont work in your case because the Spring application and the Redis instance will run in separate containers. In order to fix this, add the following line to the Spring project's `application.properties` file:

```
spring.redis.host=redis
```

After this rebuild the project and also rebuild the docker image.

This will work, because Docker will reference Redis inside the internal network as its' container name, which is `container_name: redis` in your case.